# Can the iPad Mail app show the message list full screen?

Tags: email, ipad, fullscreen

I just got an iPad (not an iPad 2) and I would like to see the list of messages in the Mail app full screen and not just in the side bar, like they are now. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry no, Mail.app on iPad only has two views.

In Portrait mode, the message list slides in from the left.  You can swipe left and right to change the view to account and folder list and back again, however you cannot resize the pane, although it feels like you should be able to in this view.

In Landscape mode, the message list is permanently fixed in position and width; you can no longer swipe to change the content.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a solution but I just noticed this behaviour.

if the email has a link in it, click it to launch safari. At top left corner of the screen there is in small font an triangle/arrow you can click to return to the mail app. When I click on that it returns to the email in full screen without the email list pane on left side. Mind you the mail msg still does not span the full width of the screen in landscape. And I'm not sure if this is replicable in all emails with links.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. Just by chance I gave a good tap to the message and it popped up without the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't. I have an iPad and I can't access all messages at once, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

No that is incorrect, at this time it cannot be swiped away or hidden or resized etc. however I did find a patchwork solution for the moment that accomplishes full page reading until Google execs use their own app & see the glaring design flaw & do an easy code fix. Here it is: simply tap on forward or reply & then when the email opens full screen for sensible reading, just tap the lowest right iPad keyboard key that closes the keyboard & when thru reading your email full page just hit cancel & delete the "draft" message you created. Just a few seconds really & one feels slightly foolish in this techno age & with Google to have to do this at all, however it works great....

Comment: The question was about Apple's built-in Mail app, not Gmail.